# "Error configuring filters" FFmpeg issue while using Vogon

Tags: python-2.7, ffmpeg

Prerequisites:

> vogon, python 2.7, ffmpeg 2.3.6(newer versions caused + one more error:
>   "Error configuring complex filters" due to vogon outdate itself, i
>   suppose)
>
> ```
>  sample_project/
>     ├── adwords_video_csv.py
>     ├── adwords_video_csv.pyc
>     ├── assets
>     │   ├── car_ad.mp4
>     │   ├── README.txt
>     │   └── vogon.png
>     ├── edit_config.py
>     ├── output
>     │   └── README.txt
>     ├── sample.csv
>     ├── sample.json
>     ├── sample_win.json
>     ├── vogon.py
>     ├── vogon.pyc
>     ├── yt_upload.py
>     └── yt_upload.pyc
> ```

Getting such a message after executing command:

```
python vogon.py sample.json --noauth_local_webserver
```

> ```
> Input #1, image2, from 'assets/vogon.png':
>   Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: N/A
>     Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba, 400x223 [SAR 2835:2835 DAR 400:223], 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
> [Parsed_movie_1 @ 0x1b35480] Failed to avformat_open_input '/tmp/vogon_Ql9UW7.gif'
> [AVFilterGraph @ 0x1af08e0] Error initializing filter 'movie' with args '/tmp/vogon_Ql9UW7.gif'
> Error configuring filters.
> ```

```
vogon.py -h: 

positional arguments:
  config_file           Configuration JSON file

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  --auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME
                        Hostname when running a local web server.
  --noauth_local_webserver
                        Do not run a local web server.
  --auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]
                        Port web server should listen on.
  --logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}
                        Set the logging level of detail.
  --youtube_upload      Upload generated videos to YouTube
  --preview_line PREVIEW_LINE
                        Generate only one video, for the given CSV line number
```

Makes me think it is an ffmgep issue. What could it be?

Comment: `Failed to avformat_open_input '/tmp/vogon_Ql9UW7.gif'` --> does file exist at that path?

Comment: Seems like the folder is full of 'vogon_blahblah.txt' like files, not a sign of a gif-ext. files.